# Are usings guarding for all eventualities?

Tags: c#, using

I've found the following passage.

```
using (TextWriter w1 = new StringWriter(...))
using (XmlWriter w2 = new XmlTextWriter(w1))
using (StringReader r1 = new StringReader(...))
using (XmlTextReader r2 = new XmlTextReader(r1))
{
  _xslt.Transform(r2, w2);
  ...
  FileOperations.LockFiles();

  w1.Close();
  w2.Close();
  r1.Close();
  r2.Close();
}
```

My suggestion is (besides renaming, of course) that we could remove the last four statements, since those are declared using *using* and will be closed and disposed properly when the framework feels like it.

However, one of the developers questioned me and asked a very disturbing question. "*Are you **entirely** sure?*". Then I got chicken feet and postponed the answer. Is there anything I could be missing?

Comment: the [`Using` explanation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) for VB includes the note: *Because the TextWriter and TextReader classes implement the IDisposable interface, the code can use Using statements to ensure that the file is correctly closed after the write and read operations.*

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov He's not asking if he should write out `close` 4 times *instead* of using a `using`, he's asking if adding them *in addition to* using a `using` is adding value.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, it is indeed covering a strictly smaller number of cases, and it's *not* useful.  The code being not useful because it adds no value is different than the code handling *less* cases.  The code is pointless and can be removed, but it's not *actively harmful* to have it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have a slight impression that you're misunderstanding the question. The question is not, as one might wrongfully assumed, how to use *using* nor *should I skip *using* in favor of explicit closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `using` blocks will always dispose the objects, no matter what. (Well, short of events like a power outage...)

Also, the disposing of the objects is very predictable, that will always happen at the end of the `using` block. (Once the objects are disposed, they are removed from the finalizer queue and are just regular managed objects that can be garbage collected, which happens when the garbage collector finds it convenient.)

In contrast, the `Close` calls will only be called if there are no unhandled exceptions inside the block. If you wanted them to surely be executed you would place them in `finally` blocks so that they are exected even if there is an exception. (That's what the `using` blocks are using to make sure that they can always dispose the objects.)

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of circumstances in which a `using` won't dispose of the resource in question.  For example, if you pull the plug on the machine while the `using` is running, the `finally` block (which the `using` is translated to) won't run.

There is no situation in which the finally block wouldn't get run in which duplicating the same cleanup steps inside the `using` would be any better suited to handle.

Comment: Oh, this was one convoluted grammar there, mate. Just to verify that I got it right in plain(er) English. "*`Close()` ain't saving what `using` can't protect.*" Right? I'll go ahead and remove the closings right away. I'm not sure why I'm always so afraid of relying on `using` for disposable classes. Must be the implicity of it. You know - "*are you **entiiiirelly** sure?*" Well... Apparently not...   :)

Answer (score 1):

If disputes like this ever come up, just fire up ILSpy (http://ilspy.net/) and peek inside the framework to see what it is actually doing on the Dispose that gets called from the end of the using statement.

In this case, you are right and all four of StringWriter, StringReader, XmlTextReader, and XmlTextWriter do their disposal work in the Dispose method and Close simply calls Dispose, so those four lines are redundant. (But note that StringWriter and StringReader don't seem to do anything interesting in their Dispose methods.)